# How to access programmatically the associated dataType of a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, datatemplate

I have:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type svgEdit:UserControlSvgEditModel}">
        <svgEdit:UserControlSvgEdit />
</DataTemplate>
```

I want to get programmatically the type: svgEdit:UserControlSvgEdit

I do:

```
        // Here the obj Type is the key to the resource, it works but
        var key = new System.Windows.DataTemplateKey(obj.GetType());
        var dataTemplate = (DataTemplate)DockSite.FindResource(key);
        // I don't know how to get the DataTemplate associated type ????
        var tc = dataTemplate.Template as TemplateContent;
```

But I can't find how to retrieve the associated type ?

Note: I need to instanciate the template content programatically and pass it to a DockSite (Docking Manager)

Comment: What do you mean by "the associated type"? Are you looking to obtain a `Type` reference value? If so, what type specifically are you trying to determine? If not, what _are_ you trying to determine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DataTemplate.LoadContent() method will give the root element within the DataTemplate.Using that we can get the data type of the template content. The modified code will look like this,

```
        var key = new System.Windows.DataTemplateKey(typeof(ProductsViewModel));
        var dataTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource(key);

        var tc = dataTemplate.LoadContent().GetType();
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(tc);
```